# Flask App in Docker Container not accessible

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a simple flask app, which runs in a docker container, which I do not want to access via the localhost. Therefore I set the host = "0.0.0.0".

Flask App:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(
debug=True
, use_reloader = False
, host = "0.0.0.0"
)
```

When I run this locally everything works as expected.

Then I build my Docker with the following parameters:

```
# tell the port number the container should expose 
EXPOSE 5000
# run the application
CMD ["python", "/usr/src/app/main.py" ]
```

Afterwards I build my docker container with the following command:

```
docker build -t my_app:latest .
```

and run it:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 my_app:latest
```

It starts the container:

```
* Serving Flask app 'main' (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: on
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
* Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Somehow thecontainer is now running on two adresses and only `http://127.0.0.1:5000` is accessible.

I already tried various proposed solution but cannot find a solution for my issue.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Accessible via `http://localhost:5000` on the docker host? Because that's what the port forwarding via `-p` does. So assuming you docker host is called `myhost`, you should be able to see `http://myhost:5000` on its network. Do you?

Comment: Accesible via `http://127.0.0.1:5000` but not on `http://172.17.0.2:5000`

Comment: That's a Docker-internal IP address and you can safely ignore it.  The output you show here is normal, and it sounds like you can connect to the container via the published port, so everything is fine?

Comment: Thanks for the input, big missunderstanding on my part.